# Java and Android regex difference

Tags: java, android, regex

Good day! 
I have a regex pattern :

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z_\\$][\\w\\$]*(?:\\.[a-zA-Z_\\$][\\w\\$]*)*$");
```

It should tell me if java / android package name is legal or not.
It works fine on desktop java, but it failures on android devices

Lets say I have some package names :

```
 ". .", "ПАвыапЫВАПыва", "com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v7_neon", ...
```

Test should show that the only valid package is "com.mxtech.ffmpeg.v7_neon", but is also shows that test string

```
" _ПАвыапЫВАПыва\_ "
```

is valid. Why? (It is Cyrillic. )

What is the difference between Android and Desktop realizations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that `\w` in Android regex is Unicode aware.

Replace with `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to only match ASCII letters, digits and an underscore.

See the [Android `Pattern` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Note that these built-in classes don't just cover the traditional ASCII range. For example, `\w` is equivalent to the character class `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}]`. **If you actually want to match only ASCII characters, specify the explicit characters you want**.

Comment: Ah... Didn't know that.